# cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem Unary Function

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to automate grid and block size choices in my Cuda code. In my case, the amount of shared memory needed depends on the number of threads.The function has the following syntax.

```
__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem ( int* minGridSize, int* blockSize, T func, UnaryFunction blockSizeToDynamicSMemSize, int  blockSizeLimit = 0 )
```

I tried defining a unary function as following.

```
struct unaryfn: std::unary_function<int, int> {
    int operator()(int i) const { return 12* i; }

};
```

Then, I call the CUDA API function as following.

```
  int blockSize;   // The launch configurator returned block size
    int minGridSize; // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the
    // maximum occupancy for a full device launch
    int gridSize;    // The actual grid size needed, based on input size
    unaryfn::argument_type blk;
    unaryfn::result_type result;
    unaryfn ufn;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem(&minGridSize, &blockSize,
                                                   CUDAExclVolRepulsionenergy, ufn(), 0);
    std::cout<<(nint +blockSize -1) / blockSize<<" "<<blockSize<<endl;
```

When I compile, I get an error

> error: function "unaryfn::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list
>               object type is: unaryfn
>   How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Solved! Removing parenthesis on the unary function in function call helped.  cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem(&minGridSize, &blockSize,
                                                   CUDAExclVolRepulsionenergy, ufn(), 0);

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Removing parenthesis on the unary function in function call helped. cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizeVariableSMem(&minGridSize, &blockSize, CUDAExclVolRepulsionenergy, ufn(), 0);